# Integrate some function

Tags: calculus

Any good ideas on how to calculate the following integral? $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp\left(-\frac{a^2x^2+x^2}{2}\right)\;dx$$

I tried to do it by taking parts, but it becomes more complex.

Comment: Substitute $u = \frac{x^2}{2}$, $du = x\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-\frac{(a^2+1)}2 x^2}\,dx$$
Now substitute $\frac{(a^2+1)x^2}{2} = t $ which gives $xdx = \frac{dt}{a^2+1}$ making our integral
 $$I=\frac{1}{a^2+1} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\,dt$$ Integrating we get $$I=\frac{1}{a^2+1}\cdot [-e^{-t}]_0 ^\infty = \frac{1}{a^2+1}\cdot [1-0] = \frac{1}{a^2+1}$$ fianlly we get $$I=\frac{1}{1+a^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$I=\int xe^{-\frac{(a^2+1)}2 x^2}\,dx$$ let
$$\frac{(a^2+1)}2 x^2=t^2 \implies x=\frac{\sqrt{2} t}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \implies I=\frac{1 }{a^2+1}\int 2t\, e^{-t^2} \,dt$$ which looks simple.

Comment: (+1) Hello Claude!  How are you my friend?

Comment: @MarkViola. Hi Mark ! Fine. What about you ?

Comment: I am doing OK .